# How to send JSON request with guzzle6 and Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, api, guzzle, guzzle6

From an API I need to send the request in this format:

```
Sample Request Body
{
  "first_name": "adam.west",
  "last_name": "adam.west",
  "email_address": "adam.west@example.com",
  "phone": {
    "number": "11111111111",
    "country_code": "UK",
    "phone_type": "Mobile",
    "extension": "124"
  },
  "comment": "comment",
}
```

so with Laravel and Guzzle6, I write this:

```
$res1 = $client1->post('https://example.com/someurl', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
            ],

   'json' => [

        'first_name' => $FirstName,
        'last_name' => $Surname,
        'email_address' => $Email,
        'phone' => [
            $phone['number'] = $Mobile,
            $phone['country_code'] = $MobileCountryCode,
            $phone['phone_type'] = 'Mobile',
            $phone['extension'] = $request->dialCode,
        ],
        'comment' => $comment,

    ]
]);
```

Everything is fine except `phone` element - What is the proper way to send phone element - because from API response I got error message "Phone could not be empty"

Comment: You're doing standard variable assignments instead of key value assignments in your phone array, take another look at that.    Should be `'number' => $Mobile,`

Comment: I tried this but response from API is again "Phone should not be empty"

Comment: Well, you may want to update the code in your question to show what you tried.

Comment: @Devon I tried again and works well. Thanks for HELP very much!